# The effect of particle accelerator on electrons/positrons spin axis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electrons

Since most particle accelerators rely on magnetic fields to accelerate charged particle beams, does this mean that all the produced electrons' spin arrows are aligned?

Answer (score 0):

No. The electrons go through [Larmor precession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_precession) while they are inside the magnetic field which is an oscillation so it doesn't fix any spin component since there is no selective apparatus (in the most general case).